# how can I Import and index rdf data in solr from virtuoso sparql endpoint

Tags: solr, rdf, dataimporthandler, virtuoso

I am trying to implement solr dataimport handler in solr using jdbc driver method.

My use case is
I have RDF data in virtuoso and i want to index this data in solr using dataimport handler ( Auto commit )

Here is my code

solrconfig.xml

```
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="virt_dialect-.*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="virtjdbc-.*\.jar" />

<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="solr.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="config">db-data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

db-data-config.xml

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource driver="virtuoso.jdbc4.Driver" url="jdbc:virtuoso://localhost:1111/" user="dba" password "dba" />
    <document>
        <entity name="item" query="SELECT ?S, ?P, ?O FROM <http://localhost:8890/sparql> { ?S ?P ?O }"
                deltaQuery="select id from item where last_modified > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'">
            <field column="subject" name="item.S" />
            <field column="description" name="item.P" />
            <field column="title" name="item.O" />
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

I am also trying to follow this link 
http://fatac.github.io/configuration.html
But because of new in this technology I can not implement this correctly.
Thanks

Comment: Does any error occur when you try to run this or what else happens?

Comment: no. i did not get any error. but when i click on execute query button query is not compiling ( same as i did not press button/ no operation ).

Answer (score 0):

in case this is still relevant for s/o

1. < > need be escaped (< , > , ...)
2. the sparql query needs to start with keyword "SPARQL", otherwise virtuoso will interpret it as an SQL query
3. the sparql query itself is not correct, except you have a graph that is really named http://localhost:8890/sparql (note that what is used in the query as graph is the default sparql endpoint url itself, which is not needed, since we're accessing data via jdbc).
4. you need to cast the bindings to strings, otherwise you'll get a solr exception stating the solr doesn't know how to serialize virtuoso.jdbc4.VirtuosoExtendedString)
5. "column" refers to the bindingName in the sparql query.
6. "name" refers to the solr document's fieldname

assuming the required driver is found and you'd like to index dcterms:abstract texts, the following data config should work

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource driver="virtuoso.jdbc4.Driver" url="jdbc:virtuoso://localhost:1111/" user="dba" password="dba" />
<document>
    <entity name="item" query="SPARQL SELECT (STR(?s) AS ?s) (STR(?o) AS ?o) FROM &lt;<urn:graph.to.be.indexed>&gt; WHERE { ?s &lt;http://purl.org/dc/terms/abstract&gt; ?o FILTER(?o!='')}">
        <field column="s" name="id" />
        <field column="o" name="abstract_txt_en" />
    </entity>
</document>
```